# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, html, formdata

В общем, пробую работу с FormData и немного php, но при отправке формы вылетает ошибка "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0".
HTML и JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formElem">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" value="John">
    Картинка: <input type="file" name="picture" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
    formElem.onsubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:63342/07.07.21_FormData/dz8_3/formAnswer.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(formElem)
        });

        let result = await response.json();

    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
?>
<hr>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<hr>
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
```

Скрин ошибки
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Такая ошибка говорит о том что сервер вернул в ответе **не** JSON. Если посмотреть на PHP-код в вопросе, то становится понятно что возвращается действительно не JSON, а вывод `var_dump`'ов. Итак, в чем именно заключается вопрос? Если для тестов хочешь видеть отправленное аяксом, то используй замечательный ресурс httpbin.org

Comment: Ну, на картинке действительно ничего даже отдаленно напоминающего JSON не видно,

Comment: а как тогда правильно вывести массивы var_dump'ов?

Comment: _«а как тогда правильно вывести массивы var_dump'ов?»_ - смотря что считать правильным. Для похапэ-человеков, и стандартный вывод var_dump'а вполне правильный и приятный. Если хочешь возвращать JSON, то используй [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), только не тремя последовательными echo/print, это не сработает как ты вероятно ожидаешь (вместо этого, либо оберни три массива в один общий, либо выводи каждый по своему условию).